# Не работает команда в AHK для смены аудиоустройства

Tags: ahk, ahk-script

Возникла проблема с AHK кодом. Мне надо поменять устройство вывода аудио на "Динамики". В отдельном файле всё работает, но когда я добавляю туда остальной код, то работать перестаёт. В чём причина, и как исправить? Подскажите пожалуйста!
Команда(работает отдельно):

```
Run, nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice "Динамики"
```

Код(команда в нём не работает):

```
Run, nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice "Динамики"
Run, steam://open/bigpicture
```